# MPF MVVM object not fire property changed event when a field is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have object user

```
public class User
{
  public string FirstName {get; set:}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

My ViewModel implemented INotifyPropertyChanged

```
private User _myUser;
public User MyUser
{
    get
     {
       return _myUser;
     }
    set
     {
        _myUser = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyUser");
     }
}
```

Textbox object of xaml is binding to MyUser.FirstName, Mode = TwoWay

When the text field of the TextBox is changed set property of the object is not fired. What should be changed to fire a set property of the MyUser object.

Comment: Do the same for `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Comment: If you bind to `MyUser.FirstName`, it's only the setter of the `FirstName` property of `MyUser` that will fire.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `MyUser` property so why would an event be raised telling you that you are? Your view model should have separate properties for the first name and last name if those are the values that will be changing.

Comment: I understand that if you bind Text property to FirstName and implements in ViewModel

Comment: I understand that if you bind Text property to FirstName and implements in ViewMode
private string _firstName
public string FirstName
{
    get
     {
       return _firstName;
     }
    set
     {
        _firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
     }
}l

set properties will be fired when I update the value of TextBox.
Do we have any mechanism to force change in set MyUser property when 
Text ="{Binding MyUser.FirstName}" of the TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to `MyUser.FirstName`, it's only the setter of the `FirstName` property of `User` object that is returned by the `MyUser` property that will fire:

```
public class User
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; //<- set a breakpoint here }
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The `TextBox` sets a `string` property. It cannot set a `User` property.